# CA 1811 in windows phone 7.5

Tags: c#, .net, windows-phone-7

FxCop gives "Avoid uncalled private code" to all the event handlers eg: tap, applicationbar button click etc.

Comment: You shall ask a question, not only state the obvious. So I'll do it for you: "Will my phone explode?" The answer is "No." You should just ignore the message - or you could make all event handlers public.

Comment: FxCop provides recommended _guidelines_. They are not the be-all and end-all of programming godhood. Take them as hints, ignore the ones that are irrelevant or fix them to get actual, relevant hints. =)

Comment: @HDWProduction I guess I didn't offend you in any way.... and a polite reply would have been better

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The analyzer just looks at the C# code and sees the handlers as simple private methods that are never called.

They are linked in XAML, by name as string, but that is out of sight for the analyzer.

So it is a harmless warning that you can safely ignore or disable.